# How I can get intagram photo url with youtube-dl lib?

Tags: youtube-dl

I want to create my first RoR application for downloading video/photo (like [this one](https://justforlink.info))content from popular websites. I found youtube-dl.rb gem and configured downloading videos from instagram, but I can't get images from photo and gallery Instagram posts. I should to use API directly or another gem. Can I do this only with youtube-dl library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Instagram API directly. youtube-dl library only for videos and metadata for videos.